# Match regex pattern that isn't within a bbcode tag

Tags: php, regex

I am attempting to create a regex patten that will match words in a string that begin with `@`

Regex that solves this initial problem is `'~(@\w+)~'`

A second requirement of the code is that it must also ignore any matches that occur within `[quote]` and `[/quote]` tags

A couple of attempts that have failed are:

```
(?:[0-9]+|~(@\w+)~)(?![0-9a-z]*\[\/[a-z]+\])

/[quote[\s\]][\s\S]*?\/quote](*SKIP)(*F)|~(@\w+)~/i
```

Example: the following string  should have an array output as displayed:

```
$results = [];
$string = "@friends @john [quote]@and @jane[/quote] @doe";

//run regex match
preg_match_all('regex', $string, $results);

//dump results
var_dump($results[1]);

//results: array consisting of:
    [1]=>"@friends"
    [2]=>"@john"
    [3]=>"@doe
```

Comment: I think it's simple to remove `\[quote\].+?\[\/quote\]` from a string and then find by your 1st regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the following regex (based on [another related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2909930/3832970)):

```
'~(\[quote](?:(?1)|.)*?\[/quote])(*SKIP)(*F)|@\w+~s'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yAz19Q/2/). The regex accounts for nested `[quote]` tags.

**Details**

- `(\[quote](?:(?1)|.)*?\[/quote])(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches the pattern inside capturing parentheses and then `(*SKIP)(*F)` make the regex engine omit the matched text:

  - `\[quote]` - a literal `[quote]` string
  - `(?:(?1)|.)*?` - any 0+ (but as few as possible) occurrences of the whole Group 1 pattern (`(?1)`) or any char (`.`)
  - `\[/quote]` - a literal `[/quote]` string
- `|` - or
- `@\w+` - a `@` followed with 1+ word chars.

[PHP demo](https://ideone.com/j1Cc1C):

```
$results = [];
$string = "@friends @john [quote]@and @jane[/quote] @doe";
$rx = '~(\[quote\](?:(?1)|.)*?\[/quote])(*SKIP)(*F)|@\w+~s';
preg_match_all($rx, $string, $results);
print_r($results[0]);
// => Array ( [0] => @friends [1] => @john [2] => @doe )
```