# Regex excluding matches wrapped in specific bbcode tags

Tags: javascript, php, regex, bbcode

I'm trying to replace double quotes with curly quotes, except when the text is wrapped in certain tags, like [quote] and [code].

**Sample input**

```
[quote="Name"][b]Alice[/b] said, "Hello world!"[/quote]
<p>"Why no goodbye?" replied [b]Bob[/b]. "It's always Hello!"</p>
```

**Expected output**

```
[quote="Name"][b]Alice[/b] said, "Hello world!"[/quote]
<p>“Why no goodbye?” replied [b]Bob[/b]. “It's always Hello!”</p>
```

I figured how to elegantly achieve what I want in PHP by using `(*SKIP)(*F)`, however my code will be run in javascript, and the javascript solution is less than ideal.

Right now I'm splitting the string at those tags, running the replace, then putting the string together:

```
var o = 3;
a = a
    .split(/(\[(?<first>(?:icode|quote|code))[^\]]*?\](?:[\s]*?.)*?[\s]*?\[\/(?:\k<first>)\])/i)
    .map(function(x,i) {
        if (i == o-1 && x) {
            x = '';
        }
        else if (i == o && x)
        {
            x = x.replace(/(?![^<]*>|[^\[]*\])"([^"]*?)"/gi, '“$1”')
            o = o+3;
        }
        return x;
    }).join('');
```

**Javascript Regex Breakdown**

1. Inside `split()`:

   - `(\[(?<first>icode|quote|code)[^\]]*?\](?:.)*?\[\/(\k<first>)\])` - captures the pattern inside parentheses:

     - `\[(?<first>quote|code|icode)[^\]]*?\]` - a `[quote]`, `[code]`, or `[icode]` opening tag, with or without parameters like `=html`, eg `[code=html]`
     - `(?:[\s]*?.)*?` - any 0+ (as few as possible) occurrences of any char (`.`), preceded or not by whitespace, so it doesn't break if the opening tag is followed by a line break
     - `[\s]*?` - 0+ whitespaces
     - `\[\/(\k<first>)\]` - `[\quote]`, `[\code]`, or `[\icode]` closing tags. Matches the text captured in the `(?<first>)` group. Eg: if it's a *quote* opening tag, it'll be a *quote* closing tag
2. Inside `replace()`:

   - `(?![^<]*>|[^\[]*\])"([^"]*?)"` - captures text inside double quotes:

     - `(?![^<]*>|[^\[]*\])` - negative lookahead, looks for characters (that aren't `<` or `[`) followed by  either `>` or `]` and discards them, so it won't match anything *inside* bbcode and html tags. Eg: `[spoiler="Name"]` or `<span style="color: #24c4f9">`. Note that matches *wrapped* in tags are left untouched.
     - `"` - literal opening double quotes character.
     - `([^"]*?)` - any 0+ character, except double quotes.
     - `"` - literal closing double quotes character.

**SPLIT() REGEX DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/Ugy3GG/1

That's awful, because the replace is executed multiple times.

---

Meanwhile, the same result can be achieved with a single PHP regex. The regex I wrote was based on [Match regex pattern that isn't within a bbcode tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48180896/match-regex-pattern-that-isnt-within-a-bbcode-tag).

```
(\[(?<first>quote|code|icode)[^\]]*?\](?:[\s]*?.)*?[\s]*?\[\/(\k<first>)\])(*SKIP)(*F)|(?![^<]*>|[^\[]*\])"([^"]*?)"
```

**PHP Regex Breakdown**

- `(\[(?<first>quote|code|icode)[^\]]*?\](?:[\s]*?.)*?[\s]*?\[\/(\k<first>)\])(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches the pattern inside capturing parentheses just like javascript `split()` above, then `(*SKIP)(*F)` make the regex engine omit the matched text.
- `|` - or
- `(?![^<]*>|[^\[]*\])"([^"]*?)"` - captures text inside double quotes in the same way javascript `replace()` does

**PHP DEMO:** https://regex101.com/r/fB0lyI/1

The beauty of this regex is that it only needs to be run once. No splitting and joining of strings. Is there a way to implement it in javascript?

Comment: Actually I think this is pretty close to as good as it gets; parsing dom with regex is simply ugly. If you want a more clean solution I would consider actually parsing dom instead of using regex.

Comment: There are no curly quotes in given input strings. Please consider providing an expected output from a given input string.

Comment: @revo There shouldn't be curly quotes in the input, since they're to be added in the output. They aren't really important, the point of the regex is to replace {thing} with {something} while leaving matches wrapped in the specified bbcode tags untouched. I added a short input/output example to the question, but given that's a regex can fail in multiple ways, for something more thorough there's a longer sample input in the demos.

Comment: Since this task includes processing html it doesn't guarantee to be %100 bulletproof. But using the second side of alternation, please check this https://jsbin.com/wulobewomi/edit?js,console

Comment: @revo Oh, that's clever and beautiful! Care to add it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because JS lacks backtracking verbs you will need to consume those bracketed chunks but later replace them as is. By obtaining the second side of the alternation from your own regex the final regex would be:

```
\[(quote|i?code)[^\]]*\][\s\S]*?\[\/\1\]|(?![^<]*>|[^\[]*\])"([^"]*)"
```

But the tricky part is using a callback function with `replace()` method:

```
str.replace(regex, function($0, $1, $2) {
    return $1 ? $0 : '“'  + $2 + '”';
})
```

Above ternary operator returns `$0` (whole match) if first capturing group exists otherwise it encloses second capturing group value in curly quotes and returns it.

Note: this may fail in different cases.

See [live demo here](https://jsbin.com/wulobewomi/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 1):

Nested markup is hard to parse with rx, and JS's RegExp in particular. Complex regular expressions also hard to read, maintain, and debug. If your needs are simple, a tag content replacement with some banned tags excluded, consider a simple code-based alternative to run-on RegExps:

```
function curly(str) {
    var excludes = {
        quote: 1,
        code: 1,
        icode: 1
    },
    xpath = [];

    return str.split(/(\[[^\]]+\])/) // breakup by tag markup
        .map(x => { // for each tag and content:
            if (x[0] === "[") { // tag markup:
                if (x[1] === "/") { // close tag
                    xpath.pop(); // remove from current path
                } else { // open tag
                    xpath.push(x.slice(1).split(/\W/)[0]); // add to current path
                } //end if open/close tag
            } else { // tag content
                if (xpath.every(tag =>!excludes[tag])) x = x.replace(/"/g, function repr() {
                    return (repr.z = !repr.z) ? "“" : "”"; // flip flop return value (naive)
                });
            } //end if markup or content?
            return x;
        }) // end term map
        .join("");
} /* end curly() */

var input = `[quote="Name"][b]Alice[/b] said, "Hello world!"[/quote]
<p>"Why no goodbye?" replied [b]Bob[/b]. "It's always Hello!"</p>`;

var wants = `[quote="Name"][b]Alice[/b] said, "Hello world!"[/quote]
<p>“Why no goodbye?” replied [b]Bob[/b]. “It's always Hello!”</p>`;

curly(input) == wants; // true
```

To my eyes, even though it a bit longer, code allows documentation, indentation, and explicit naming that makes these sort of semi-complicated logical operations easier to understand.

If your needs are more complex, use a true BBCode parser for JavaScript and map/filter/reduce it's model as needed.